# Having a tab content that is always open on load?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have card (bootstrap 4) which inside has 2 options, and then within each option is another 2 options.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lay8xp27/

I have tried using `in active` and `active` but they aren't working.  They just have the radio button highlighted but the content won't appear loaded.

How can I have it so the first option is open on page load?

Comment: Do you mean you want the first bullet point to be selected on page load? In both tabs?

Comment: yes - i want the first radio to be selected on default when the page loads with the content appearing on load as well.  Most importantly, the content being loaded

Comment: Hm, I saved the fiddle with the content within but it doesn't seem to appear on the link.  Goign to fix

Comment: @DriveItLikeYouStoleIt updated : http://jsfiddle.net/Lay8xp27/

Comment: well nvm i got it.. kind of dumb of me.  i just had to use `active` in the one place for the tab pane

Comment: Great. That was actually going to be my next thought - sounds like it's similar to the basic jQuery accordion widget which also uses `active`. (https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: Yes, I believe the bootstrap accordion is based off of jquery javascript anyway so makes sense. --- not sure tho.  thanks for helping tho!